# Script for hotkey which stops the runnig python program

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, keyboard

I would like to be able to stop my python program at any time using a key combination (for example ctrl+S).
Can someone write a short script for me?
Thank you very much

Comment: `Ctrl+C` already interrupts python scripts

Comment: No  i tried this, it doesnt work